# Maximal Function Estimate for Characteristic Function of ball

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inequality

In a problem set, I was tasked with showing the inequality: there exist constants $c_n,C_n>0$ only depending on the dimension $n$ such that

$$ \frac{c_nR^n}{(\|x\|+R)^n} \leq M(\chi_{B(0,R)})(x) \leq \frac{C_nR^n}{(\|x\|+R)^n}, \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n. $$

Here $\chi_{B(0,R)}$ is the characteristic function of the ball $B(0,R)$, and $M(\chi_{B(0,R)})$ is its uncentered maximal function.

I was easily able to prove this holds for $n=1$, but in the case $n>1$  could only prove that

$$\frac{R^n}{(\|x\|+R)^n} \leq M(\chi_{B(0,R)})(x), \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n $$
and
$$ M(\chi_{B(0,R)})(x) = 1 , \quad \forall x\in B(0,R). $$

I am stuck with one remaining case.

In particular, I am unable to show that
$$ M(\chi_{B(0,R)})(x) \leq \frac{2^nR^n}{(\|x\|+R)^n} $$
when $\|x\|>R$.

I am convinced this inequality holds, because the right side is the averaged integral over the smallest (closed) ball which contains $x$ and $B(0,R)$.

$$ ⨍_{B((1-\frac{R}{\|x\|})x,\frac{1}{2}(\|x\|+R))} \chi_{(B(0,R))}(y) dy = \frac{\omega_nR^n}{\omega_n(\frac{1}{2}(\|x\|+R))^n} = \frac{2^nR^n}{(\|x\|+R)^n}. $$

It is geometrically "obvious" why
$$ \frac{1}{\omega_nr^n} \int_{B(z,r)} \chi_{B(0,R)}(y) dy \leq \frac{2^nR^n}{(\|x\|+R)^n} \qquad (*)$$
should hold for any other ball $B(z,r)$ containing $x$, but I cannot prove it.

How can we show $(*)$ when $B(z,r)$ is a ball containing $x$ which intersects $B(0,R)$ but doesn't contain $B(0,R)$? (if they don't intersect, the integral in $(*)$ vanishes; if $B(0,R)\subset B(z,r)$, the inequality is trivial.)

Answer (score 0):

The book "Classical Fourier analysis 3rd edition" by Loukas Grafakos, Chapter 2.1 on page 89 maybe a reference for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).